# Google Optimize redirect tests with gtag

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, gatsby, gtag.js, google-optimize

I am developing a static site using gatsby.js. I need to set up a redirect test using Google Optimize. I created the redirect test at https://optimize.google.com and started it. After that, I used this code to set up the redirect tests in the site:

```js
gtag('config', 'UA-48341628-1', {'optimize_id': 'GTM-XXXXXX'});
gtag('set', {'expId': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'});
gtag('set', {'expVar':'New Signup Page'});
```

The purpose of the test is to redirect some people from `/signup` to `/sign-up`. But when I am going to `/signup` nothing happens even if I am setting 0 weight to `/signup` and 100% weight to `/sign-up`. What am I doing wrong?

My Google Optimize setup:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [Analytics field-reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#expVar), the Experiment Variation must be provided as the index of the selected variation, not by its name. So in your case:

```
gtag('set', {'expVar':'1'});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem existed as I've tried to use `localhost` as the base URL which has not been recognized by Google Optimize. I've solved the problem by using `http://test.io` as the base URL and have added it to my `/etc/hosts` mapped to `127.0.0.1`.